# I was trying to find the magical number in the given range but its giving me error

Tags: c++, c++11

This is giving me the error like i can't be used in std::is_floating_point because i is not a constant.

```
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
     int k=18;
    int prime=0, nonprime=0;
    int N=100;
 int i=1, z=0, a=0, b=0;
 int req = 1;
    for(i=2; i<=N; i++){
         if(std::is_floating_point<i/10>){
            for(z=1; z<=i; z++){
                if((i/z) == i){
                    if((i/z) == 0){
                       prime=prime+1; 
                    }else{
                        nonprime=nonprime+1;
                    }
```

Comment: std::is_floating_point  checks for types, not for values. Even if it did, it isn't clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: And `if((i/z) == i){` is only true if `z` is 1.

Comment: In a way, the answer is no.`i` is an `int`, so `i/10` will be result in an `int`.

Comment: What do you expect `std::is_floating_point` to do, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if(std::is_floating_point<i/10>)
```

The value of `i` is not known at compile time, so it cannot be used to expand a template.

Next, the `is_floating_point` template, as @AdnanY points out, is expecting a type not a number. You can turn the expression into a type with `decltype`,

```
if(std::is_floating_point<decltype(i/10)>::value)
```

and this also deals with the problem of i not being a compile-time constant. The value of `i` isn't constant, but its type is. Note the `::value` on the end there. Once the template is expanded, you need `::value` to get the resulting `bool` out of it.

Final point, `i/10` is integer division all the way through so the result is guaranteed to be an integer. The `if` will always test false and skip the body.

Here's bit of example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    for (int i=1; i < 1000; i++)
        std::cout << std::boolalpha
                  << std::is_floating_point<decltype(i/10)>::value
                  << '\n';
}
```

You can set the upper bound of the loop to whatever you want, and you'll never get anything but false.

Answer (score 0):

If you adhere to use `template`, making a `compile-time loop` wheel is a must:

Here is a good reference with c++11(which reduces difficulties): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857354/Compile-Time-Loops-with-Cplusplus-Creating-a-Gener

Then, welcome to black magic : )